# complexity of mergesort with linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

i have code for mergesort using linked list,it works fine,my question what is complexity of this algorithm?is it O(nlog(n))?also is it stable?i am interested because   as i know mergesort is stable,what about using linked list?if we have elements  with some equal with each-other,does  this code preserve orders of elements?thanks a lot

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;

};
struct node *addnode(int number,struct node *next);
struct node*mergesort(struct node *head);
struct node *merge(struct node *one,struct node *two);

int main(void){
    struct node *head;
    struct node *current;
    struct node *next;
    int test[]={8,3,1,4,2,5,7,0,11,14,6};
    int n=sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
    int i;
    head=NULL;
     for (i=0;i<n;i++)
         head=addnode(test[i],head);
     i=0;
     head=mergesort(head);
    printf("before----after sort \n");
    for (current=head;current!=NULL;current=current->next)
        printf("%4d\t%4d\n",test[i++],current->number);

    /* free list */
    for (current=head;current!=NULL;current=current->next)
        next=current->next;free(current);
return 0;
}

struct node *addnode(int number,struct node* next){
    struct node *tnode;
    tnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(*tnode));
    if(tnode!=NULL){
        tnode->number=number;
        tnode->next=next;
            }

     return tnode;
     }
struct node *mergesort(struct node *head){

    struct node *head_one;
    struct node *head_two;
    if((head==NULL) ||(head->next==NULL))
         return head;
    head_one=head;
    head_two=head->next;
    while( (head_two!=NULL) &&(head_two->next!=NULL)){
        head=head->next;
        head_two=head->next->next;
        }
    head_two=head->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    return merge(mergesort(head_one),mergesort(head_two));
    }
struct node *merge(struct node*head_one,struct node*head_two){

    struct node *head_three;
    if(head_one==NULL)
         return head_two;
    if(head_two==NULL)
         return head_one;
    if(head_one->number<head_two->number){

head_three=head_one;
head_three->next=merge(head_one->next,head_two);
    }
    else
    {

        head_three=head_two;
        head_three->next=merge(head_one,head_two->next);


    }

    return head_three;
    }
```

Comment: What analysis have you done so far?  You can answer your own question by running the algorithm on different inputs and plotting the runtime, as well as checking whether it's stable.

Comment: Questions like "what is the complexity of mergesort?" and "is mergesort stable" are trivially easy to answer with websearch.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The OP seems to be aware of Mergesort's complexity and stability in general, but is wondering about this specific implementation.

Comment: @templatetypedef : this would only give the average time complexity.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a typo in your code. With it corrected, it is indeed stable, and of `O(n log n)` complexity. Although to be sure, you really **should reimplement** your `merge` as **a loop** instead of recursion. C doesn't have tail call optimization (right?), so this can mess things up there:

```
struct node *mergesort(struct node *head){

    struct node *head_one;
    struct node *head_two;
    if((head==NULL) ||(head->next==NULL))
         return head;
    head_one=head;
    head_two=head->next;
    while( (head_two!=NULL) &&(head_two->next!=NULL)){
        head=head->next;
        // head_two=head->next->next;      // -- the typo, corrected:
        head_two=head_two->next->next;
        }
    head_two=head->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    return merge(mergesort(head_one),mergesort(head_two));
    }
```

And while we're at it, *change* your workflow from

```
    return merge(mergesort(head_one),mergesort(head_two));
```

to

```
    struct node *p1, *p2; 
    // ......
    p1 = mergesort(head_one);
    p2 = mergesort(head_two);
    return merge(p1,p2);
```

it'll be much easier on the stack this way (will use much less of it).

In general, this here is what's known as *top-down* mergesort. You could also do it in a *bottom-up* fashion, by initially sorting the consecutive chunks of two elements each, then merging them into (thus, now, sorted) chunks of 4 elements, then merging *those* pairwise, into chunks of 8 elements, etc., until only one chunk is left - the sorted list.

To get extra fancy (and efficient), instead of starting with the 2-chunks, start by splitting the list into monotonic *runs*, i.e. increasing sequences, and decreasing sequences - re-linking the latter ones in reverse as you go - thus segmenting the original list according to its innate order, so it's likely there will be fewer initial chunks to merge; then proceed merging those *pairwise* repeatedly, as before, until only one is left in the end.

Comment: I must have missed something, but isn't the "advancing head_one and head_two" part `O(n)` time itself? That said, how is the overall time complexity still `O(nlogn)`? Because in array you can get the mid point with `O(1)` time without the need to increment "fast" and "slow" pointers

Comment: @benjaminz yes, the advancing of pointers is ~3n/2; it achieves breaking the list into two halves; there is thus O(log n) steps (repeated halving is the dual of repeated doubling: x = 2^n === log2(x) = n ) . Merging is also O(n). -- in array the split is O(1) but the merge is still O(n), so, still n log n overall, for the log n steps. -- I've edited, to mention the bottom-up scheme: there's no recursive splitting then, just repeated merging.

Comment: Thanks @WillNess , I gave a second thought and realized that the "merging" step is O(n), so the "advancing", which is O(n/2) is **not** any worse than the "merging" step, so it doesn't make much of difference towards the overall O(nlogn) running time =)

Comment: @benjaminz the advancing is ~ 1.5n, and yes it doesn't matter complexity-wise. see the answer by Christoph and discussion in its comments; also my edit; for the preferred method which is the bottom-up mergesort.

Answer (score 1):

**How *not* to implement mergesort for linked lists**

- do not recursively bisect the list - random access isn't free
- <del>do not divide into sublists of size `1` and `n - 1`, as [explained by ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9626337/48015)</del>

**How to implement mergesort for linked lists**

Instead of using bisection, build the lists up by maintaining a stack of already sorted sublists. That is, start by pushing lists of size `1` to the stack and merge down until you reach a list of greater size; you don't actually need to store the list sizes if you can figure out the math behind that.

The sorting algorithm will be stable iff the merge function is. A stable version would build the merged list from scratch by always taking a single element from the lists, and using the first list in case of equality. An unstable, but better performing version would add to the merged list in chunks, avoiding unnecessary re-linking after each element.

Comment: recursively bisecting singly-linked list into halves adds `O(n log n)` complexity to the algorithm. I.e., a constant factor here (after the typo is fixed; see my answer). Building your own stack explicitly is fine if you do it better than a compiler writer already did. But you don't need it, to build your sorted list in a bottom up manner - you only need `log n` passes over the list with a size parameter `n` of `2,4,8, ...`, each time relink-merging *in-place* chunks of size `n` under assumption that chunks of `n/2` size are already sorted. cf. Richard O'Keefe such code in Prolog and Scheme.

Comment: ... so this indeed is a great idea! That way there's no split, only merge. :)

Comment: @WillNess: the actual performance gain will depend on the specific use case, of course, but I've seen runtime cut in half by replacing a recursive version with a stack-based one; also, the stack-based version is on-line, ie great when reading data from disk (or other sources with latency)...

Comment: aha, *on-line* - so you mean to merge chunks as soon as possible, in a "skewed" fashion. That way it's also more "incremental", having the minimal element *so far*, while the input is being consumed. Nice. It is also possible to initial-partition according to "runs" in order, with varying length, re-linking on discovery even for descending ones. But on in-memory input all this is unnecessary, stack isn't needed, and you just complete full scans of the list with 2,4,8... scheme, merging the chunks *up* pairwise, until only one's left. All in a loop of course, no recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Mergesort means split&merge. The splitting in the fragment below is not perfect (it leads to quadratic behavior on equally distributed runlengths, see the comment from Christoph)), but it will do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
        struct llist *next;
        char *payload;
        };

int llist_cmp(struct llist *l, struct llist *r);
struct llist * llist_split(struct llist **hnd
                        , int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) );
struct llist * llist_merge(struct llist *one, struct llist *two
                        , int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) );
struct llist * llist_sort(struct llist *ptr
                        , int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) );

struct llist * llist_split(struct llist **hnd, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) )
{
struct llist *this, *save, **tail;

for (save=NULL, tail = &save; this = *hnd; ) {
        if (! this->next) break;
        if ( cmp( this, this->next) <= 0) { hnd = &this->next; continue; }
        *tail = this->next;
        this->next = this->next->next;
        tail = &(*tail)->next;
        *tail = NULL;
        }
return save;
}

struct llist * llist_merge(struct llist *one, struct llist *two, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) )
{
struct llist *result, **tail;

for (result=NULL, tail = &result; one && two; tail = &(*tail)->next ) {
        if (cmp(one,two) <=0) { *tail = one; one=one->next; }
        else { *tail = two; two=two->next; }
        }
*tail = one ? one: two;
return result;
}
struct llist * llist_sort(struct llist *ptr, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r) )
{
struct llist *save;

save=llist_split(&ptr, cmp);
if (!save) return ptr;

save = llist_sort(save, cmp);

return llist_merge(ptr, save, cmp);
}

int llist_cmp(struct llist *l, struct llist *r)

{
if (!l) return 1;
if (!r) return -1;
return strcmp(l->payload,r->payload);
}


struct llist lists[] =
{{ lists+1, "one" }
,{ lists+2, "two" }
,{ lists+3, "three" }
,{ lists+4, "four" }
,{ lists+5, "five" }
,{ lists+6, "six" }
,{ lists+7, "seven" }
,{ lists+8, "eight" }
,{ lists+9, "nine" }
,{ NULL, "ten" }
        };

int main()
{
struct llist *root,*tmp;

root = lists;

fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "initial:" );
for (tmp=root; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tmp->payload);
        }

fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "sorting..." );
root = llist_sort(root, llist_cmp);
for (tmp=root; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tmp->payload);
        }
fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "done." );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632583/6309):

> In general, this here is what's known as top-down mergesort.
>
> You could also do it in a bottom-up fashion, by initially sorting the consecutive chunks of two elements each, then merging them into (thus, now, sorted) chunks of 4 elements, then merging those pairwise, into chunks of 8 elements, etc., until only one chunk is left - the sorted list.

As an example of such an algorithm, consider the one used by Git in [`mergesort.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/afc72b5d3afa5537d38047c9dffb81b50518e19d/mergesort.c#L4-L84):

It comes from Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), which **optimizes the mergesort implementation used to sort linked list**.

---

See [commit c90cfc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c90cfc225baaf64af311f7e2953267e4de636205) (08 Oct 2021), and [commit afc72b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc72b5d3afa5537d38047c9dffb81b50518e19d), [commit 40bc872](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40bc872adbeb9eff4bb2504730b901decb0aead5), [commit 84edc40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84edc40676c5b21df872ec5004a48f706486961f), [commit f1ed4ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1ed4ce9e314a7d21229f2fa9004d6faa512293c), [commit 1aa5899](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1aa589922bcc5fca42887f1f122adcb7c9d1da5a), [commit 0cecb75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cecb75531e1ab525f42943be71f4a213d023412), [commit e031e97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e031e9719d21c11102870b8037bdda995dede5e0), [commit d536a71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d536a711699dd369083b83dd98f3df1fdf2b08f0), [commit 2e67010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e6701017ed6bfb9481e9d5ba5abb29cf4120321) (01 Oct 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0ef0809](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ef08090d2a391e0ce037eafd2b391e3f76b1060), 18 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mergesort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc72b5d3afa5537d38047c9dffb81b50518e19d): use ranks stack
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> The bottom-up mergesort implementation needs to skip through sublists a lot.
>
> A recursive version could avoid that, but would require `log2(n)` stack frames.
>
> Solution: Explicitly manage a stack of sorted sublists of various lengths instead to avoid fast-forwarding while also keeping a lid on memory usage.
>
> While this patch was developed independently, a ranks stack is also used in [`mono/mono/mono/eglib/sort.frag.h`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/e100285775e333c2cc66dca29e990b616c352509/mono/eglib/sort.frag.h#L40-L48) by the [Mono project](https://github.com/mono/mono).
>
> The idea is to keep slots for `log2(n_max)` sorted sublists, one for each power of 2.
> Such a construct can accommodate lists of any length up to `n_max`.
> Since there is a known maximum number of items (effectively `SIZE_MAX`), we can pre-allocate the whole rank stack.
>
> We add items one by one, which is akin to incrementing a binary number.
> Make use of that by keeping track of the number of items and check bits in it instead of checking for `NULL` in the rank stack when checking if a sublist of a certain rank exists, in order to avoid memory accesses.
>
> - The first item can go into the empty first slot as a sublist of length `2^0`.
> - The second one needs to be merged with the previous sublist and the result goes into the empty second slot as a sublist of length 2^1.
> - The third one goes into vacated first slot and so on.
>   At the end we merge all the sublists to get the result.
>
> The new version still performs a stable sort by making sure to put items seen earlier first when the compare function indicates equality.
> That's done by preferring items from sublists with a higher rank.
>
> The new merge function also tries to minimize the number of operations.
> Like [`blame.c::blame_merge()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/afc72b5d3afa5537d38047c9dffb81b50518e19d/blame.c#L1053-L1062), the function doesn't set the next pointer if it already points to the right item, and it exits when it reaches the end of one of the two sublists that it's given.
> The old code couldn't do the latter because it kept all items in a single list.
>
> The number of comparisons stays the same, though.
> Here's example output of "`test-tool mergesort test`" for the rand distributions with the most number of comparisons with the ranks stack:
>
> ```
> $ t/helper/test-tool mergesort test | awk '
>     NR > 1 && $1 != "rand" {next}
>     $7 > max[$3] {max[$3] = $7; line[$3] = $0}
>     END {for (n in line) print line[n]}
> '
> ```
>
> ```
> distribut mode                    n        m get_next set_next  compare verdict
> rand      copy                  100       32      669      420      569 OK
> rand      dither               1023       64     9997     5396     8974 OK
> rand      dither               1024      512    10007     6159     8983 OK
> rand      dither               1025      256    10993     5988     9968 OK
> ```
>
> And here the differences to before:
>
> ```
> distribut mode                    n        m get_next set_next  compare
> rand      copy                  100       32     -515     -280        0
> rand      dither               1023       64    -6376    -4834        0
> rand      dither               1024      512    -6377    -4081        0
> rand      dither               1025      256    -7461    -5287        0
> ```
>
> The numbers of `get_next` and `set_next` calls are reduced significantly.
>
> NB: These winners are different than the ones shown in the patch that introduced the unriffle mode because the addition of the `unriffle_skewed` mode in between changed the consumption of rand() values.