# Selection sort with linked list's

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, structure

I have the following data structure:

```
struct scoreentry_node {
    struct scoreentry_node *next;
    int score;
    char name[1];    
};  
typedef struct scoreentry_node *score_entry;
```

I am trying to create a function that consumes my structure in order and arranges them in ascending order based on the name. I want to modify the input without allocating any memory or freeing anything:

I've tried your suggestions:

```
void selectionsort(score_entry *a) {
    for (; *a != NULL; *a = (*a)->next) {
        score_entry *minafteri = a;
        // find position of minimal element
        for (score_entry j = (*a)->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) {
            if (strcmp(j->name, (*minafteri)->name) == -1) {
                *minafteri = j;
            }
        }
        // swap minimal element to front
        score_entry tmp = *a;
        a = minafteri;
        *minafteri = tmp;
    }
}
```

I'm testing the above code with the following:

```
score_entry x = add(8, "bob", (add( 8 , "jill", (add (2, "alfred", NULL)))));
iprint("",x);
selectionsort(&x);
iprint("", x);
clear(x); //Frees the whole list
```

`iprint()` prints the score and name fields in the struct. My add function is as follows:

```
score_entry add(int in, char *n, score_entry en) {      
   score_entry r = malloc(sizeof(struct scoreentry_node) + strlen(n));
   r->score = in;
   strcpy(r->name, n);
   r->next = en;  
   return r;   
}
```

I'm getting heap errors and my second print doesn't print the sorted list, it prints nothing. What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Selection sort is a bad sorting algorithm for singly-linked lists (or lists in general, for that matter). If you're looking for a sorting algorithm that is both optimal in runtime and doesn't allocate any memory, try mergesort.

Comment: `char name[1];` is a bit small. For the string to be null-terminated, the only valid string would be "", which would make comparing the names rather useless.

Comment: @Philip for merge sort won't i need two list's ? i only have one ..

Comment: Now I see you use the "struct hack".

Comment: The "struct hack" is defining a `char name[1];` as the last struct element, but actually allocating more space (than 1 char) and trusting that the compiler will not limit your access to the thing to the size in the definition. Before c99 this was illegal (but often allowed by the implementation), with c99 came the VLA.

Comment: Is that why the above is not working ?

Comment: Could be, could be not (behaviour is still undefined). You probably you made a trivial error somewhere. I won't look into it (because I think that selection sort on a linked list is the wrong thing to do, and I don't like hiding pointers behind typedefs)

Comment: @wildplasser im trying mergesort, but im not sure how to split up my inputted list into 2 list's ?

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624467/complexity-of-mergesort-with-linked-list/9634059#9634059 is a split + merge sort I posted in another topic.

Answer (score 1):

besides passing  the pointer by address (see comments below) you also need to fix the way you swap elements too

```
void selectionsort(score_entry *a) {
  for (; *a != NULL; *a = (*a)->next) 
  {
     score_entry *minafteri = a;
     // find position of minimal element
     for (score_entry j = (*a)->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) {
       if (strcmp(j->name, (*minafteri)->name) == -1) {
         *minafteri = j;
       }
      }
     // swap minimal element to front
     score_entry tmp = *a;
     a = minafteri; // put the minimal node to current position
     tmp->next = (*a)->next ; //fix the links
     (*minafteri)->next=tmp; //fix the links
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that pass by reference doesn't exist in C, strictly. You are passing a value (the pointer) and dereferencing the pointer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c">

Comment: This solution is broken: `*a = (*a)->next` -> `a = &(*a)->next` and the list is still corrupted since you do not update the link from the previous node to the one you move.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the argument to `selectionsort` *by reference*:

```
void selectionsort(score_entry *a) {
    for (; *a != NULL; *a = (*a)->next) 
    {
      score_entry *minafteri = a;
      // find position of minimal element
      for (score_entry j = (*a)->next; j != NULL; j = j->next) {
      if (strcmp(j->name, (*minafteri)->name) == -1) {
         *minafteri = j;
      }
    }
     // swap minimal element to front
      score_entry tmp = *a;
      a = minafteri;
      *minafteri = tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm i have typedef struct scoreentry_node *score_entry; isn't it a pointer to the struct already ?

Comment: @Beginnernato Here you need to pass the reference to the pointer, so a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: So it would take in somethin like `selectionsort(&x)`; where x is a pointer a struct ? and i after i call selection sort, x would be sorted ?

Comment: editted questions, I'm having problems with the new `selection sort`

Comment: This solution is broken: `*a = (*a)->next` -> `a = &(*a)->next` and the list is still corrupted since you do not update the link from the previous node to the one you move.

Answer (score 0):

This code is hideous! Not only have you not provided us with all of the necessities to reproduce your problem (we can't compile this!), but you've hidden pointer abstractions behind `typedef` (also a nightmare for us). Generally speaking, one shouldn't even *use* linked lists in C anymore let alone *sort* them...

Nonetheless, there are two answers here.

---

`*minafteri = j;`  found within your *find* loop actually modifies your list! Why should your *find* loop be modifying your list?

Answer: it shouldn't! By instead assigning `minafteri = &j->next`, you won't be modifying the list with your find loop...

---

Alternatively, you could perform the swap inside of that loop.

`*minafteri = j;` would need to swap the following, in this order:

- `(*minafteri)->next` and `j->next`
- `*minafteri` and `j`

Do you think that single line of code is capable of performing those two swaps? Well, it gets half way through one of them... and removes a heap of elements from your list in the process!

---

The following appears to be a faulty attempt swapping elements:

```
score_entry *minafteri = a; // half of assigning `a` to `a`
/* SNIP!
 * Nothing assigns to `minafteri`  in this snippet.
 * To assign to `minafteri` write something like `minafteri = fubar;` */
score_entry tmp = *a;       // half of assigning `*a` to `*a`
a = minafteri;              // rest of assigning `a` to `a`
*minafteri = tmp;           // rest of assigning `*a` to `*a`
```

It's really just assigning `*a` to `*a` and `a` to `a`... Do you think you need to do that?

I'd have thought you'd notice *that* when you were creating your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... Ohh, wait a minute! Shame on you!

---

Focus on swapping two nodes within a list as a smaller task. Once you've done that, consider taking on this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `if (strcmp(j->name, (*minafteri)->name) == -1) {` is incorrect: `strcmp()` does not necessarily return -1 when the first string is less than the second, it can return any negative value.
- The way you adjust the links in order to move the lower entry is incorrect: you cannot update the link from the previous node to the one you move to the start. The list is corrupted.

Here is an improved version:

```
void selectionsort(score_entry *a) {
    for (; *a != NULL; a = &(*a)->next) {
        // find position of minimal element
        score_entry *least = a;
        for (score_entry *b = &(*a)->next; *b != NULL; b = &(*b)->next) {
            if (strcmp((*b)->name, (*least)->name) < 0) {
                least = b;
            }
        }
        if (least != a) {
            // swap minimal element to front
            score_entry n = *least;
            *least = n->next;   /* unlink node */
            n->next = *a;       /* insert node at start */
            *a = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java Implementation of Selection Sort on Linked List:

> - Time Complexity: O(n^2)
> - Space Complexity: O(1) - Selection sort is    In-Place sorting algorithm

```
class Solution 
{
    public ListNode selectionSortList(ListNode head)
    {
        if(head != null)
        {
            swap(head, findMinimumNode(head));
            selectionSortList(head.next);
        }
        return head;
    }

    private void swap(ListNode x, ListNode y)
    {
        if(x != y)
        {
            int temp = x.val;
            x.val = y.val;
            y.val = temp;    
        }
    }

    private ListNode findMinimumNode(ListNode head)
    {
        if(head.next == null)
            return head;

        ListNode minimumNode = head;

        for(ListNode current = head.next; current != null; current = current.next)
        {
            if(minimumNode.val > current.val)
                minimumNode = current;
        }
        return minimumNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C, not Java.